# Synchonise 2 input fields, can it be done using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can jQuery synchronise or copy the text of one input field to another when input A is modified? For example:

```
<input id="input_A" type="text" /> ...If I type something here

<input id="input_B" type="text" /> ... It will be copied here
```

Can jQuery Do this?

Comment: jQuery plugin for synchronising the values of two fields: https://github.com/ain/jquery-fieldsync

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#input_A").bind("keyup paste", function() {
    $("#input_B").val($(this).val());
});
```

For jQuery 1.7+ use `on`:

```
$("#input_A").on("keyup paste", function() {
    $("#input_B").val($(this).val());
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/GTtMp/1/)

– *Update August 2017* –

[The `input` event is now well supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-event), so you can use that in place of combining both `keyup` and `paste` events:

```js
$("#input_A").on("input", function() {
  $("#input_B").val(this.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input_A" type="text" />
<input id="input_B" type="text" />
```

Comment: Don't forget the `paste` event

Comment: Just missing the opening bracket for `$this)`.

Comment: One small note: if you're using jQuery 1.7 or later, it's recommended to use the `on` function instead of the `bind` function.

Comment: What if you had 12 inputs you wanted to sync up, would you use 12 different ids?  See my answer for a more flexible method.

Answer (score 7):

Late answer, but I prefer this way since it doesn't require multiple element ids:

```
$('input.sync').on('keyup paste', function() {
     $('input.sync').not(this).val($(this).val());
});
```

Garrett

Comment: I prefer this answer, 'cause the synchronization in this case is a two-way.

Comment: way better than the acccepted value, this allows syncing multiple inputs that share the same class name. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

During writing, pasting,  etc value will be copied.
In jQuery < 1.7 instead `on` use `bind`.

```
$( "#input_A" ).on( "paste keyup", function() { 
     $( "#input_B" ).val( $( this ).val() );
});
```

Comment: The `focus` is unnecessary and `keydown` happens before value changed. Rory has it correctly.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it can. Bind a keypress or keyup event and copy over the value:

```
$('#input_A').keyup(function() {
    $('#input_B').val($(this).val());
});
```

Or, if you only want the value to be copied after the user is finished editing it, use the blur event with the same handler. This has an added advantage that if the user pastes text into `input_A`, it also will be copied into `input_B`.

```
$('#input_A').blur(function() {
    $('#input_B').val($(this).val());
});
```

Here's a [working example with keyup](http://jsfiddle.net/g2xcx/) and [one with blur](http://jsfiddle.net/QSqxs/).