# synchronize two HTML elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js, textarea

I have a text area

```
<textarea id="realAreaWhereUserTypes"></textarea>
```

And i have a hidden input field liek follow.

```
<input id="hiddenUserInput" />
```

The textArea contains the value like follows :

```
This is my friend @bingo_mingo and this is my another friend @lingo_tingo
```

The hidden field fields contains the same text but in different format.

```
This is my friend @a142f2f0-1eda-11e3-ad5f-3c970e02b4ec:bingo_mingo and this is my another friend @a143edr0-1eda-11e3-ad5f-3c970e02b4ec:lingo_tingo
```

I want these two fields to synchronize. And whenever i delete something from the real text Area the hidden should get updated.Also if i start deleting the @admin_admin  in the main text the hidden text should update accordingly.

Is there any jquery plugin avaiable avaiable for this.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used one. Have you looked for any? This may be one: http://github.com/ain/jquery-fieldsync  Also, this question is a duplicate: [Synchonise 2 input fields, can it be done using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8803416/jquery-sync-2-input-fields-can-it-be-done)

Answer (score 1):

Use `.clone()` from Jquery.  It's easy http://api.jquery.com/clone/

Answer (score 0):

You can create a listener that will update the hidden field with the updated text whenever it is changed.

```
$("#realAreaWhereUserTypes").bind("keyup paste", function() {
    var newStr = formatName($(this).val());
    $("#hiddenUserInput").val(newStr);
}); 

function formatName(str){
   // Do whatever change you need here.
}
```